# Tag rename request - [tinkers-constuct] -> [tinkers-construct]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

The current tag for the Minecraft mod Tinkers' Construct is misspelled. Can we rename it to the correct spelling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

' is not allowed in tags, so we cannot use it, but I've fixed the typo.

Comment: I didn't know punctuation was not allowed, sorry. I edited out the apostrophe in my question. Thank you for fixing it